# Insert Array Values into MySQL DB Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem on Inserting array values into db table...pls help me to solve this problem...thanks in advance...

```
$array1=([0]=>val1,[1]=>val2,[2]=>val3);
$array2=([0]=>val1,[1]=>val2,[2]=>val3);
$array3=([0]=>val1,[1]=>val2,[2]=>val3);

INSERT INTO table1 (id,date,col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES (1,now(),'$array1','$array2','$array3',50);
```

Comment: Use [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Comment: Do you want the field to store a whole array or just one row per element?

Comment: if you want to store array you can implode elements in string, and when you need to read them later use explode.

Comment: i want to add one row per element....

Comment: you cannot insert an array directly into a table. You need to use a foreach to iterate through all the elements of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this, (**this is just an example**)

```
foreach($array as $row){
  $query="INSERT INTO 
  table1 (id,date,col1,col2,col3,col4)
  VALUE
  (1,now(),".$row['yourfieldname'].",".$row['yourfieldname'].",".$row['yourfieldname'].",50)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO table1 (id,date,col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES (1,now(),'$array1[0]','$array1[1]','$array1[2]',50);

Where the brackets ([]) indicate which array position you want to insert.

Comment: i used this format using for loop it's not working...it adds 'A,r' in db table

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert in one row use `implode()` like

```
$arr1 = implode(',', $array1)
$arr2 = implode(',', $array2)
$arr3 = implode(',', $array3)

$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (id,date,col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES (1,now(),'$arr1','$arr2','$arr3',50)";
```

else you need to use `for()` or `foreach()`

```
for($i =0; $i <=count($array1); $i++){
  $query="INSERT INTO 
  table1 (id,date,col1,col2,col3,col4)
  VALUE
  (1,now(),".$row[$i].",".$row[$i].",".$row[$i].",50)";
}
```

For forech you can use @sagar's answer